# iText 2.1.7 in commercial Project

Tags: licensing, lgpl

This question was originally asked on Stack Overflow but since licensing questions are [off topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing) I move it here. So here comes the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705697/itext-2-1-7-in-commercial-project) about this open source library:

---

I want to use the Java PDF Library iText in a commercial Project (for generating simple PDF reports), which is distributed as CDs. I don't plan to change the original source-code from iText – just using it. So as far as I know it uses the AGPL after Version 2.1.7 , but before it uses MPL/LGPL.

My questions are:

1. Can I use it in my commercial Project?
2. Can I choose which licence to use (MPL/LGPL)?
3. Is it enough to ship the licence texts or do I need to ship the Source code (from iText) too?
4. Is it okay if I wrap everything in one Exe-File or do I need to have the iText jar in a separate Folder?
5. Do I need to mention the use of iText inside my Program (like a Info message or something) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And the answer was:

First, please note, I am not a lawyer!

For iText LGPL/MPL version 2.1.7:

- Q: Can I use it in my commercial Project? A: Yes if you comply with LGPL.
- Q: Can I choose which licence to use (MPL/LGPL)? A: There is no "choosing" the license is LGPL/MPL. You can however choose to comply to the LGPL license OR to comply to MPL license (which better suits your needs).
- Q: Is it enough to ship the licence texts or do I need to ship the Source code (from iText) too? A: E.g. a download link should suffice
- Q: Do I need to mention the use of iText inside my Program (like a Info message or something)? A: Yes

For iText AGPL version > 5.X / 7.X

- Q: Can I use it in my commercial Project? A: Yes if you open source your whole project (thus also AGPL it) otherwise no.
- Q: Can I choose which licence to use (MPL/LGPL)? A: There is no "chosing" the license is what it is: AGPL
- Q: Is it enough to ship the licence texts or do I need to ship the Source code (from iText) too? A: You have to supply the whole sourcode of everything - but a download link should suffice.
- Q: Do I need to mention the use of iText inside my Program (like a Info message or something)? A: Yes

Whether you should still use an old version of iText (pre 5.X) is a totally different question.

Comment: It seems you copied this answer from somewhere. Could you provide proper attribution, e.g. a link to the original answerer?

Comment: Update: I found the original link. Only visisble to users with enough reputation though...

Comment: For transparency sake: The original question on SO, which is now linked in this question, was also self-answered by @Lonzak.

Comment: Thanks for the flowers ;-) but just for clarification: Answered but not self-answered. I posted it here since I wanted to link the answer for several other questions...

Comment: @Lonzak since you're still keeping this answer up to date (thanks!) could you also consider accepting it, so that the question is put to bed?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Migrate to OpenPdf, it will fix the issues of iText 2.1.7 and it is open source and up to date.

https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF

You cannot use iText open source 2.1.7 because of IP/license issues of the code fragments in the code.